# Filter Exact word not wholeword

Tags: php, html, regex

Want to replace only Exact words in array list,current code working expect it checking wholeword content and replace:(

Example:-

$String= This is a testing ,Happy test

It will replace "testing" as t--ting and test as t--t

Wanted out put:-
only filter test as t--t,ignore when filter word include in with other characters

**Code**

```
  function filter($string) {            

    $wordlist = array(
                'test' => 't--t'

    );
                   foreach ($wordlist as $word => $filter) {
                        $word = "/{$word}/";
                        preg_match_all($word, $string, $matches);
                            foreach ($matches[0] as $bword) {
                                $pattern = "/{$bword}/";
                                $string = preg_replace($pattern, $filter, $string);
                            } 
                    } 

    return $string;
}

echo filter($string);
```

i think pattern was incorrect,Could help me to find correct pattern or any working code applicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Extract = Exact` = typo?

If you want to match the exact word, use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

`/\btest\b/` matches "exact" `test`. To also match caseless add `i` [flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php): `/\btest\b/i`

Also note, that you can use arrays with [preg_replace() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). So function could be:

```
$string= "This is a testing ,Happy test";

function filter($string)
{            
  $wordlist = array(
  '/\btest\b/' => 't--t'
  );

  return preg_replace(array_keys($wordlist), array_values($wordlist), $string);
}

echo filter($string);
```

[Test at eval.in](https://eval.in/201436)

Comment: @Randy Suitt Your input is utf-8? Than use `u` [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php): `/\btest\b/u` Note, that both, pattern and input have to be utf-8 if so. Or `/\btest\b/ui` for utf-8 and caseless matching.

Comment: @RandySuitt If ASCII in editor and input UTF-8, need to utf-8 encode the pattern only, e.g. `'/\b'.utf8_encode("wörd").'\b/ui'`

Comment: @RandySuitt Because on eval.in the written code is UTF-8 already: Than you only need `'/\bwörd\b/ui' => ' w****'` ([see example](https://eval.in/201468))

Comment: @RandySuitt If you don't get it going with the word boundaries, you could also use negative lookbehind/ahead as an alternative: `/(?<!\w)test(?!\w)/i` or `/(?<!\w)test(?!\w)/ui`; `\w` is [shorthand](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for a word-character. Check if this matches your needs [at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/xO9kV2/1) on the right side, there's explanation.