# Bad word check in PHP using stripos

Tags: php, stripos

I implemented this "bad word" check function in php:

```
# bad word detector
function check_badwords($string) {
    $badwords = array(a number of words some may find inappropriate for SE);
    foreach($badwords as $item) {
        if(stripos($string, $item) !== false) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It works alright, except I'm having a little problem. If the $string is:

```
Who is the best guitarist ever?
```

...it returns true, because there is a match with **Who** ($string) and **ho** (in $badwords array). How could the function be modified so that it only checks for complete words, and not just *part of words*?

- check_badwords('She is a ho'); //should return true
- check_badwords('Who is she?'); //should return false

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177013/filter-exact-word-not-wholeword this should help.

Comment: [How to find full words only in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898825/how-to-find-full-words-only-in-string) as another duplicate.

Comment: Your array of words isn't sufficiently exhaustive. Without even scrolling I can already tell that you're missing a whole class of compound words beginning with anus. Better to just split the string on space and check each word to see if it has an entry in urban dictionary.

Comment: Without sounding like a tw*t: Is it really necessary to post a big list of profanity / swear words on SO to get a programming question across? The problem could still be solved if the array contained `unicorn`, `donut` and `icecream`.

Comment: [Clbuttic rookie mistake.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to check for complete words you should use [regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php):

```
function check_badwords($string)
{
    $badwords = array(/* the big list of words here */);
    // Create the regex
    $re = '/\b('.implode('|', $badwords).')\b/';
    // Check if it matches the sentence
    return preg_match($re, $string);
}
```

**How the `regex` works**

The regular expression starts and ends with the special sequence `\b` that [matches a word boundary](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) (i.e. when a word character is followed by a non-word character or viceversa; the word characters are the letters, the digits and the underscore).

Between the two word boundaries there is a [subpattern](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php) that contains all the bad words separated by `|`. The subpattern matches any of the bad words.

If you want to know what bad word was found you can change the function:

```
function check_badwords($string)
{
    $badwords = array(/* the big list of words here */);
    $re = '/\b('.implode('|', $badwords).')\b/';
    // Check for matches, save the first match in $match
    $result = preg_match($re, $string, $match);
    // if $result is TRUE then $match[1] contains the first bad word found in $string
   return $result;
}
```

Comment: Could we just use placeholder for those words instead? I can't think of a logical reason to have profanity / swearing anywhere on SO, even if this is a valid question in and off itself.

Answer (score 1):

You probably would like to replace stripos with preg_match

if you can make it a better regex, more power to you:

```
preg_match("/\s($string){1}\s/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

Comment: `“ass”` => `false`

Comment: The quick solution of course ignores start and end of sentence, or any adjacent punctuation.

Comment: @deg you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You can even lowercase the $string and then instead using stripos or even a regular expression, just use `in_array()`. That'd match against the whole word.